# Openshift REST API endpoint(s) - need to get useful data for CMDB, especially about containers itself

Tags: openshift, cmdb

I need a help with tips on REST endpoints with usefull information which I can import inside CMDB for evidence purposes.

I found several of them (like Image, Infrastructure, Identity, User, UserIdentityMapping, Group, Project and Pod).

But because I'm not experienced in Openshift (and also in Kubernetes) I want to get help from you.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Normally the logic used for populating a CMDB is reversed , you start by deciding what needs to be documented and then you retrieve (only) that. You normally don’t import everything that a platform ***can*** provide.

Comment: @HBruijn Yes, you are right. But I first need some idea what is possible to get and in which structure. This is because I'm not experienced with it so I want to do it in other way and find out what is really needed.